# How does a single tensorflow deep neural network scale in performance with multiple gpus?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I have read that convolution networks scale very well across multiple gpus, but what about deep neural networks that don't use convolutions? The Tensorflow website provides a [multiple gpu example](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html), but it uses convolutions.

Comment: You could have multiple towers with fully connected layers instead of convolutional, and it would scale in the same way (each tower goes on separate GPU)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thanks. What is a tower?

Comment: It's the design used in the multiple GPU example you linked